# AVAssetExportSession merge videos with stereo

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I am merging multiple videos together using `AVAssetExportSession` but the videos are in stereo and the resulting video is in dual mono. Is it possible to use `AVAssetExportSession` to merge videos and maintain the stereo channels? I see it is possible to merge in stereo using `AVAssetWriter` and

```
AudioChannelLayout stereoChannelLayout = {.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo,
                .mChannelBitmap = 0,
                .mNumberChannelDescriptions = 0
            };
```

to make it stereo but I am using `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` with the `AVAssetExportSession` to handle video positioning within the merge so it would be ideal if there was a way to do it with `AVAssetExportSession`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that you can replace `AVAssetExportSession` with [`SDAVAssetExportSession`](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession). You can then specify audio settings as you would for the `AVAssetWriter` while leveraging the benefits of the `AVAssetExportSession`.

I had to change `__weak typeof(self) wself = self;` to `__weak SDAVAssetExportSession * wself = self;` on line 172 of `SDAVAssetExportSession.m`.

Comment: wow looks to be exactly what I needed. Thanks I may review dust off that old project now and give that a go cheers!